# OS X CMake: exectuable with alternative bundle name

Tags: macos, cmake, nsbundle

Problem is simple, from this kind of cmake entries:

```
add_executable(Foo
    Source1.h
    Source1.cpp
)
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME "My cool application"
    MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.mycompany.coolapplication
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@loader_path/Libraries"
    RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME TRUE
)
```

I've expected bundle with name `My cool application.app` and `Foo` hidden inside`./My cool application.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo` (spaces in bundle name are desired).

But it ends with `Foo.app`  and: `./Foo.app/Contents/MacOS/Foo`

Apparently not only I [have this problem](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2014-January/056880.html) (no answer).

Please note that my project is C++ and multiplication so cmake is best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got improved solution. Now I have different name for: target, budle and executable.

This is exact `CMakeLists.txt` file I used for testing:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CMakeTestBundleName)
add_executable(TestBubdle main.cpp extra.cpp)

set_target_properties(TestBubdle PROPERTIES
    OUTPUT_NAME "BundleName"
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    MACOSX_RPATH TRUE
    MACOSX_FRAMEWORK_IDENTIFIER com.testcmake.bundlename
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS "@loader_path/Libraries"
    RESOURCE "${RESOURCE_FILES}"
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_ENABLE_HARDENED_RUNTIME TRUE
    XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_EXECUTABLE_NAME "exeName"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is this list of properties you can set : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#properties-on-targets

MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME is not one of them and I haven't see anyone using before!

Maybe you can try this :

```
set_target_properties(Foo PROPERTIES
    ...
    OUTPUT_NAME "My cool application"
    ...
)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_NAME` is documented at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST.html